# join random number of lines untill close brace match in unix file

Tags: csh

Need to join random number of lines untill close brac match and substitute with one space in unix file . There can be multiple occurence like this in file . One liner awk , sed , perl solution will be more helpful.

Eg :

 .... 
abc_mod #( 
.h_res(3), 
.s_res(10) 
) 
u_abc_mod 
( 
.... 
.... 
.... 
def_mod #( 
.lp(4), 
.clk(9), 
.add(5), 
.d(8), 
.por(1) 
) 
u_def_mod 
( 
....

Need to match pattern equivalent to #( till 1st close brace at starting of line ) followed by one extra new line (can include random number of lines ) and substitute with single space.

Desired Output :

 .... 
abc_mod u_abc_mod 
( 
... 
def_mod u_def_mod 
( 
... 
...

Thanks

Comment: Using what tool?  `sed`?  `awk`?  And remember that you can't match "till 1st close brace", because you have multiple parens inside there.  You'll need to match until "line that starts with closed paren".

Comment: Thanks , Edited ! Any tool is fine untill the required output is available .

Comment: Can you please share using sed or awk or pcregrep/egrep , as it can be easily incorporated into csh script

Comment: Regarding "... incorporated into csh script" - see https://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt, http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/, etc. for why not to write scripts in csh.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Python solution:

```
import sys

skip = False
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not skip:
        i = line.find('#(')
        if i >= 0:
            print(line[:i], end='')
            skip = True
        else:
            print(line)
    else:
        if line == ')':
            skip = False
```

Output:

```
$  python x.py < x.tzt
abc_mod u_abc_mod
(
....
....
....
)
def_mod u_def_mod
(
....
)
```